# Index template and Home page

Tags: templates

Sorry if this seems silly but I am new to WP. I realise that Index template is the most important file. Is it ok to have Index as your "home" page, and can you just assign the Index template to the home page when setting it up in the back-end?

Comment: for homepage you can have `home.php` file

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want the Home page to be different to the Index template. In that case, I can just have the Index template and assign it to be the home page without having a Home.php?

Comment: if you don't want to use `home.php` its okey. just have the `index.php` with all homepage content. Wordpress will fallback to `index.php` if it not find the `home.php` file. Not recommended though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use home.php just as Sisir said. Copy the content from index.php to that file and you are all set.

home.php tells wordpress that that page should be the homepage in a theme so no backend settings needs to be changed.